# Hashmap iteration for a grading system

Tags: java, hashmap

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;


public class fff2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NullPointerException{
        try {
            LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> score = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
            score.put("Fail",39);
            score.put("Third Class", 49);
            score.put("Second Class, Division 2",59);
            score.put("Second Class, Division 1",69);
            score.put("First Class",70);
        
        
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
            System.out.println("What was your mark?");
        
            int mark = scan.nextInt();
        
            if(mark >100 && mark < 0) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input: out of range.");
            }
            for(String i: score.keySet()) {
                if(mark< score.get(i)) {
                    System.out.println("You got a "+i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    
        catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input, program terminating");
            
        
    }
}
```

So I am trying to make a grading system but it isn't working can i have some help please? I am trying to make it so that a mark of 40 is a pass as a third class but i want to use a hashmap to challenge myself as opposed to the switch case.

Comment: What is not working, put expected output. Btw this code is so wrong. As you don't use the hashmap as you should, and you iterate it for some reason. Also the if is wrong.

Comment: the expected output for inputting 40 would be You got a Third Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;


public class fff {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NullPointerException{
        try {
            LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> score = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();
            score.put(70, "First class");
            score.put(59, "Second Class, Division 1");
            score.put(49, "Second Class, Divison 2");
            score.put(39, "Third Class");
            
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            
            System.out.println("What was your mark?");
            
            int mark = scan.nextInt();
            
            if(mark >100 && mark < 0) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input: out of range.");
            }
            for(Integer i: score.keySet()) {
                if(mark <= 39) {
                    System.out.println("You got a Fail");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                if(mark>=i) {
                    System.out.println("You got a "+score.get(i));
                    break;
                }

                    
                }
                
                
        }
            catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input, program terminating");
                
            
        }
    
    }   
}
```

This is my final code and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want something like this:

```
        LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> score = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
        score.put("Fail",39);
        score.put("Third Class", 49);
        score.put("Second Class, Division 2",59);
        score.put("Second Class, Division 1",69);
        score.put("First Class",70);
    
    
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        System.out.println("What was your mark?");
    
        String keyScore = scan.nextString();
    
        System.out.println(score.getOrDefault(keyScore, "Invalid Input: key not in map"));
```

where on input you put one of the keys from the map, and not the value.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
score.put("First Class",70);
```

with

```
score.put("First Class",100);
```

and also replace

```
if(mark< score.get(i)) {
```

with

```
if(mark<= score.get(i)) {
```